# Nginx downloading PHP file only if .php is in the URL

Tags: php, nginx

I know this is a popular question but I haven't found anyone with my similar issue. I can serve PHP files as long as the .php extension is not in the url. For example:

If I go to `localhost` I am served my index.php file. If I go to `localhost/index.php` I download the file. Here is my config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

    # Only for nginx-naxsi used with nginx-naxsi-ui : process denied requests
    #location /RequestDenied {
    #   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;    
    #}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I am quite confused by this issue and I am wondering if anyone has experience in the matter.

Comment: Can you also post your `php.ini`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is sometimes working (so you know PHP-FPM is up and working), I'd be pretty set on this being a nginx issue. I'm suspicious of a couple of the rules in your PHP location block. They *might* be breaking in certain URLs causing nginx to dump out.

You only *need* 2 lines for catching directory indexes:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Strip that location back to that, reload nginx and see what happens.

If you need rewriting (pretty URLs in Wordpress, etc) you want to add something like this

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

But only do that once you've got standard URLs working.

Comment: I made the changes and at first it didn't work. Then I removed the cache on my browser and it worked. Thank you for your time! :)

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem, however, i also needed this line

```
include fastcgi.conf;
```

I also had

```
location ~* .+ {..}
```

and had to make sure it went after location `~ \.php$ {..}`

Comment: Hmm interesting `include fastcgi.conf;` is almost the same as `include fastcgi_params;` but additionally includes `fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;` which some users that include `include fastcgi_params;` instead of `.conf` include manually in their sites configuration.